# Use where condition for retrieving the xml data with C#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to fetch the data from an xml file. I am fetching the id of node from the previous page. And on next page I want to display the data from xml of that id. I am passing id of node using query string but when I run my code its give me this error

> System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Here is my code

```
XElement xid = XElement.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

// var id = Request.QueryString["ID"];

var doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Data/BlogContent.xml"));
var result = doc.Descendants("post")
                .Where(x => x.Element("id") == xid)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    id = x.Element("id").Value,
                    title = x.Element("title").Value,
                    Discription = x.Element("Discription").Value,
                    dt = x.Element("dt").Value,
                    mnt = x.Element("mnt").Value,
                    yr = x.Element("yr").Value
                }).OrderByDescending(x => x.id).Take(5);

Repeater1.DataSource = result;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>
  <post>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>fds</title>
    <Discription>fdsafsdf</Discription>
    <dt>21</dt>
    <mnt>6</mnt>
    <yr>2013</yr>
  </post>
</content>
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: Please include sample XML in your post.

Comment: You xml has wrong format on line 1 character 1 edit further to @Mike Precup s comment post your real xml with different tag names if you must

Comment: @MikePrecup please see the xml now

Comment: Is this the line causing the error? `XElement xid = XElement.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);`  If so, it's because you're trying to assign something that isn't XML to an `XElement`.  Try something like `int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]);`

Comment: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' and 'int'
giving me this error now

Comment: See my answer below (xid should be a string, not an int as I put in my comment) - plus there's one more issue that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't indicate the line causing the error, but I bet it's this one:

```
XElement xid = XElement.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
```

Most likely "ID" in your query string is an identifier of some sort, **not** XML - hence the error.

Something like this is what you want:

```
string xid = Request.QueryString["ID"];
```

Then you can use it in your `where` clause.

Also, there's an error in your where clause - you're trying to compare an `XElement` to a value - you need to get the value of the XElement using it's `Value` property:

```
Where(x => x.Element("id").Value == xid)
```

`XElement.Value` returns a string - so simply take the string value from the query string and use it in the comparison in your where clause.

**Everything Put Together**

```
string xid = Request.QueryString["ID"];

var doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Data/BlogContent.xml"));
var result = doc.Descendants("post")
                .Where(x => x.Element("id").Value == xid)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    id = x.Element("id").Value,
                    title = x.Element("title").Value,
                    Discription = x.Element("Discription").Value,
                    dt = x.Element("dt").Value,
                    mnt = x.Element("mnt").Value,
                    yr = x.Element("yr").Value
                }).OrderByDescending(x => x.id).Take(5);

Repeater1.DataSource = result;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I use this and i am getting this error check here at line no 27
     
Line 26:         var doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Data/BlogContent.xml"));
Line 27:         var result = doc.Descendants("post").Where(x => x.Element("id") == id).Select(x => new
Line 28:         {
Line 29:             id = x.Element("id").Value,

Comment: You need to use `x => x.Element("id").Value == id)` - the way your code is written you're trying to compare a string to an XElement.

Comment: sorry i did not add the .value first but after that i am getting this error
: System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Source Error:


Line 20:     private void BindRep()
Line 21:     {
Line 22:         XElement xid = XElement.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
Line 23:

Comment: `XElement xid = XElement.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"])` will not work.  I've posted the complete code with the two changes you need to make in my answer.

Comment: :( Giving me this error now at line 28 i think x.element("id") is empty
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:


Line 26:         var doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Data/BlogContent.xml"));
Line 27:         var result = doc.Descendants("post")
Line 28:                         .Where(x => x.Element("id").Value == xid).Select(x => new
Line 29:         {
Line 30:             id = x.Element("id").Value,

Comment: You'll have to look at the XML file.  I took the sample you gave, put it in a console app and was able to get the results you expect with no problems.  I'd also suggest stepping through the code so you can examine the values of `xid`  and `doc`.

Comment: thanks its done i had a blank node in my xml i delete that and try its working well now :) thanks for help